# [C++]Intellisense Reports Class Reference of Type <Error-Type>

Tags: c++, intellisense, class-reference

I have been trying to fix this problem for a few weeks now but nothing I have done has fixed it.  This seems to be a problem with the Intellisense information not being updated in a .cpp file.

The problem is that class reference passes for specific classes in a header file are not being recognized but Intellisense **only in the cpp file**.  In the Header file the references are read perfectly.

Here is the header file, excuse some of the mess as I am in the middle of reorganizing, merging functions, and reworking the class:

```
#ifndef DAMAGE_H
#define DAMAGE_H

#include <string>
#include "entity.h"
#include "hardPoint.h"
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

class Damage
{
public:

    Damage();

    float findDType(string dType, float damage);

    void dmgProcessing(bAttacker& bAttacker, bTarget& bTarget);

    float dTPiercing1(float damage);
    float dTPiercing2(float damage);
    float dTPiercing3(float damage);

    float dTNapalm1(float damage);
    float dTNapalm2(float damage);
    float dTNapalm3(float damage);

    float dTDesructor(float damage);

    float dTNanite1(float damage);
    float dTNanite2(float damage);
    float dTNanite3(float damage);

    float dTDDay1(float damage);
    float dTDDay2(float damage);

    float dTStealth(float damage);

    float dTFOnly(float damage);

    float dTEMP1(float damage, Player& mPlayer, Hostile args[], string target);
    float dTEMP2(float damage, Player& mPlayer, Hostile args[], string target);
    float dTEMP3(float damage, Player& mPlayer, Hostile args[], string target);

    float dTVirus1();
    float dTVirus2();
    float dTVirus3();
    float dTVirus4();

    float dTMAccel(float damage);

    void bPAttack(bool allout, bool spread, bool wsystem, bool single);

    void setupWQueue(bAttacker& bAttacker, string atype);

    void cleanWQueue();

    float processWQueue(bAttacker& bAttacker, bTarget& bTarget);
    float processSDamage(bTarget& bTarget, string wdtype);
    float processSecDamage(bTarget& bTarget);

    void setupBAT(Entity* entity1, Entity* entity2);

    bool getSDNTurns();
    bool getSDNANTurns();

private:

    vector<hardPoint> weaponQueue;

    float vDamage; //Vanilla Damage
    float mDamage; //Modified Damage
    float fDamage; //Final Damage
    float sDamage; //Secondary Damage
    float tSDamage; //total secodary damage

    int i;

    int sDNTurns, sDNANTurns; //Number of turns to apply secondary damage for (N = Napalm, NAN = Nanite)


    int dLow, dHigh;

    string wdtype; //store weapon name

    int nSDamage, nADamage, nHDamage; //Health interface variables for nanite secondary damage
};
//#endif


/*Damage Types:

piercing1: Armor Piercing, does not affect hull
piercing2: Hull Piercing, does not affect armor
piercing3: Armor and Hull piercing
napalm1: low level napalm damage, lasts two turns
napalm2: medium level napalm damage, lasts four turns
napalm3: high level napalm damage, lasts six turns
destructor: higher damage to defenses
nanite1: low level nanite damage, does 5% of HP damage for two turns
nanite2: medium level nanite damage, does 8% of HP damage for four turns
nanite3: high level nanite damage, does 15% of HP damage for eight turns
doomsday1: large scale damage, kills off 25% of population instantly along with 15% of all infrastructure and 10% of biomass
doomsday2: larger scale damage, kills off 40% of population instantly along with 25% of all infrastructure and 18% of biomass
stealth: invisible to point defenses, point defenses will still have a 2% chance to destroy a missile volley per point defense up to 10%.
frigonly: only damages frigate class ships, no damage to higher classes
null: no special damage
emp1: low level shield damage, if shields down will cripple non-emp protected target for one turn
emp2: medium level shield damage, if shields down will cripple non-emp protected target for three turns
emp3: high level shield damage, if shields down will cripple non-emp protected target for seven turns
virus1: scrambles targeting systems of enemy ship, target will not attack for two turns and loses shields
virus2: scrambles targeting systems and crashes computer, target will not attack for five turns and loses shields
virus3: scrambles targeting systems, crashes computer, and disables life support and loses shields (RTS/RPG).  Crews of ships lower then crusier class can be killed in two turns and ship can be salvaged whole (twice the resources; RTS only)
virus4: crashes all systems and injects core breach code into engines and loses shields.  35% chance that the ship will self destruct over 4 turns, after which systems reboot and core breach stopped.  10% chance per 20 tech crewmen or 5 tech module on board to avert code breach. (RTS only)
massaccel: Mass Accelerator damage bypasses shield and armor and deals direct hull damage.

*/


class bTarget
{
public:

    bTarget();

    void getShip(Entity* entity);

    Ship returnShip(Entity* entity);

    Ship* Ship;
};

class bAttacker
{
public:

    bAttacker();

    void getShip(Entity* entity);

    Ship returnShip(Entity* entity);

    Ship* Ship;
};
#endif
```

All of the reference passes pertaining to bTarget and bAttacker are find in this header file but once I place the function definitions into the .cpp file Intellisense bombs out by claiming that the definitions do not match the header declaration of void setupWQueue(error-type &bAttacker, string atype) just as an example.

However direct access to the bAttacker and bTarget classes, for the definition of the getShip function for example, are just fine.

Edit:

For the sake of being thorough in case something in it is causing this here is the cpp file as well; this will be much messier than the header for the same reason (sorry!):

```
#include <string>
#include "damage.h"
#include "planet.h"
#include "random.h"
#include "datasystem.h"

using namespace std;

#define EMP1DT 1
#define EMP2DT 3
#define EMP3DT 7

#define NP1P 0.15
#define NAN1P 0.05
#define NP2P 0.28
#define NAN2P 0.08
#define NP3P 0.46
#define NAN3P 0.15

#define NP1T 2
#define NAN1T 2
#define NP2T 4
#define NAN2T 4
#define NP3T 6
#define NAN3T 8

dataSystem ds;

int test = NAN1T;


Damage::Damage()
{

}

void Damage::dmgProcessing(bAttacker& bAttacker, bTarget& bTarget)
{
    setupWQueue(bAttacker, atype);

}


float Damage::dTEMP1(float damage, Player& mPlayer, Hostile args[], string target)
{

    if (target == mPlayer.getName()) //Consider creating main class or matrix for all fighting entities/teams to make this easier
    {
        if ((!mPlayer.Ship.isDisabled()) && (mPlayer.Ship.getSShield() == 0)) //If ship is not disabled already and shilds are 0
        {
            mPlayer.Ship.disableShip(EMP1DT);
        }

        else if ((mPlayer.Ship.getShieldStatus()) && (mPlayer.Ship.getSShield() != 0)) //If shields are enabled and are greater then 0
        {
            mDamage = damage / Random(8,10);
            return mDamage;
        }
    }

    else
    {

        for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(args)-1; i++)
        {
            if (target == args[i].getName())
            {
                if ((!args[i].Ship.isDisabled()) && (args[i].Ship.getSShield() == 0)) //If ship is not disabled already and shilds are 0
                {
                args[i].Ship.disableShip(EMP1DT);
                }

                else if ((args[i].Ship.getShieldStatus()) && (args[i].Ship.getSShield() != 0)) //If shields are enabled and are greater then 0
                {
                    mDamage = damage / Random(8,10);
                    return mDamage;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

float Damage::dTEMP2(float damage, Player& mPlayer, Hostile args[], string target)
{

    if (target == mPlayer.getName()) //Consider creating main class or matrix for all fighting entities/teams to make this easier
    {
        if ((!mPlayer.Ship.isDisabled()) && (mPlayer.Ship.getSShield() == 0)) //If ship is not disabled already and shilds are 0
        {
            mPlayer.Ship.disableShip(EMP2DT);
        }

        else if ((mPlayer.Ship.getShieldStatus()) && (mPlayer.Ship.getSShield() != 0)) //If shields are enabled and are greater then 0
        {
            mDamage = damage / Random(5,7);
            return mDamage;
        }
    }

    else
    {

        for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(args)-1; i++)
        {
            if (target == args[i].getName())
            {
                if ((!args[i].Ship.isDisabled()) && (args[i].Ship.getSShield() == 0)) //If ship is not disabled already and shilds are 0
                {
                    args[i].Ship.disableShip(EMP2DT);
                }

                else if ((args[i].Ship.getShieldStatus()) && (args[i].Ship.getSShield() != 0)) //If shields are enabled and are greater then 0
                {
                    mDamage = damage / Random(5,7);
                    return mDamage;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

float Damage::dTEMP3(float damage, Player& mPlayer, Hostile args[], string target)
{

    if (target == mPlayer.getName()) //Consider creating main class or matrix for all fighting entities/teams to make this easier
    {
        if ((!mPlayer.Ship.isDisabled()) && (mPlayer.Ship.getSShield() == 0)) //If ship is not disabled already and shilds are 0
        {
            mPlayer.Ship.disableShip(EMP3DT);
        }

        else if ((mPlayer.Ship.getShieldStatus()) && (mPlayer.Ship.getSShield() != 0)) //If shields are enabled and are greater then 0
        {
            mDamage = damage / Random(2,4);
            return mDamage;
        }
    }

    else
    {

        for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(args)-1; i++)
        {
            if (target == args[i].getName())
            {
                if ((!args[i].Ship.isDisabled()) && (args[i].Ship.getSShield() == 0)) //If ship is not disabled already and shilds are 0
                {
                    args[i].Ship.disableShip(EMP3DT);
                }

                else if ((args[i].Ship.getShieldStatus()) && (args[i].Ship.getSShield() != 0)) //If shields are enabled and are greater then 0
                {
                    mDamage = damage / Random(2,4);
                    return mDamage;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


void Damage::bPAttack(bool allout, bool spread, bool wsystem, bool single)
{
    vDamage = 0.0f;
    mDamage = 0.0f;
    fDamage = 0.0f;

    if (allout)
    {
        fDamage = processWQueue(bAttacker);

        //Check for secondary damage
        if (getSDNTurns())
        {
            fDamage += processSecDamage(bAttacker);
            sDNTurns -= 1;
        }

        if (getSDNANTurns())
        {
            fDamage += processSecDamage(bAttacker);
            sDNANTurns -= 1;
        }

        hostile.takeSDamage(fDamage);
    }

    else if (spread)
    {

    }

    else if (wsystem)
    {

    }

    else if (single)
    {

    }
}

float Damage::processWQueue(bAttacker& bAttacker,bTarget& bTarget)
{
    for (i = 0; i < weaponQueue.size(); i++)
    {
        if (weaponQueue.at(i).getHPWType() == "laser")
        {
            wdtype = bAttacker.Ship->getLWDType(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()); //send slot of current laser weapon to ship for return of item name

            dLow = bAttacker.Ship->lBanks.at(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()).hpWeapon.getWDRLow();
            dHigh = bAttacker.Ship->lBanks.at(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()).hpWeapon.getWDRHigh();
        }

        else if (weaponQueue.at(i).getHPWType() == "missile")
        {
            wdtype = bAttacker.Ship->getMWDType(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()); //send slot of current missile weapon to ship for return of item name

            dLow = bAttacker.Ship->mTurrets.at(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()).hpWeapon.getWDRLow();
            dHigh = bAttacker.Ship->mTurrets.at(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()).hpWeapon.getWDRHigh();
        }

        else if (weaponQueue.at(i).getHPWType() == "bomb")
        {
            wdtype = bAttacker.Ship->getBWDType(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()); //send slot of current bomb weapon to ship for return of item name

            dLow = bAttacker.Ship->bHolds.at(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()).hpWeapon.getWDRLow();
            dHigh = bAttacker.Ship->bHolds.at(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()).hpWeapon.getWDRHigh();
        }

        else if (weaponQueue.at(i).getHPWType() == "rail")
        {
            wdtype = bAttacker.Ship->getRWDType(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()); //send slot of current rail gun weapon to ship for return of item name

            dLow = bAttacker.Ship->rMounts.at(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()).hpWeapon.getWDRLow();
            dHigh = bAttacker.Ship->rMounts.at(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()).hpWeapon.getWDRHigh();
        }

        else if (weaponQueue.at(i).getHPWType() == "heavy")
        {
            wdtype = bAttacker.Ship->getHWDType(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()); //send slot of current heavy weapon to ship for return of item name

            dLow = bAttacker.Ship->hWBays.at(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()).hpWeapon.getWDRLow();
            dHigh = bAttacker.Ship->hWBays.at(weaponQueue.at(i).getHPSlot()).hpWeapon.getWDRHigh();
        }

        if (wdtype != "null")
        {
            vDamage += Random(dLow, dHigh);
            mDamage += processSDamage(bTarget,wdtype);
        }

        else
        {
            vDamage += Random(dLow, dHigh);
        }               
    }

    return vDamage;
}

float Damage::processSDamage(bTarget& bTarget, string wdtype)
{
    if (wdtype == "napalm1")
    {
        if (sDamage > 0.0f)
        {
            sDamage += (0.50 * (vDamage * NP1P));
        }

        else
        {
            sDamage = vDamage * NP1P;
        }

        if (sDNTurns < NP1T)
        {
            sDNTurns = NP1T;
        }

    }

    else if (wdtype == "napalm2")
    {
        if (sDamage > 0.0f)
        {
            sDamage += (0.50 * (vDamage * NP2P));
        }

        else
        {
            sDamage = vDamage * NP2P;
        }

        if (sDNTurns < NP2T)
        {
            sDNTurns = NP2T;
        }
    }

    else if (wdtype == "napalm3")
    {
        if (sDamage > 0.0f)
        {
            sDamage += (0.50 * (vDamage * NP3P));
        }

        else
        {
            sDamage = vDamage * NP3P;
        }

        if (sDNTurns < NP3T)
        {
            sDNTurns = NP3T;
        }
    }

    else if (wdtype == "nanite1")
    {
        if (nSDamage > 0.0f)
        {
            nSDamage += (0.75 * (bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN1P));
        }

        else
        {
            nSDamage = bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN1P;
        }

        if (nADamage > 0.0f)
        {
            nADamage += (0.75 * (bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN1P));
        }

        else
        {
            nADamage = bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN1P;
        }

        if (nHDamage > 0.0f)
        {
            nHDamage += (0.75 * (bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN1P));
        }

        else
        {
            nHDamage = bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN1P;
        }

        if (sDNANTurns < NAN1T)
        {
            sDNANTurns = NAN1T;
        }
    }

    else if (wdtype == "nanite2")
    {
        if (nSDamage > 0.0f)
        {
            nSDamage += (0.75 * (bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN2P));
        }

        else
        {
            nSDamage = bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN2P;
        }

        if (nADamage > 0.0f)
        {
            nADamage += (0.75 * (bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN2P));
        }

        else
        {
            nADamage = bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN2P;
        }

        if (nHDamage > 0.0f)
        {
            nHDamage += (0.75 * (bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN2P));
        }

        else
        {
            nHDamage = bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN2P;
        }

        if (sDNANTurns < NAN2T)
        {
            sDNANTurns = NAN2T;
        }
    }

    else if (wdtype == "nanite3")
    {
        if (nSDamage > 0.0f)
        {
            nSDamage += (0.75 * (bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN3P));
        }

        else
        {
            nSDamage = bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN3P;
        }

        if (nADamage > 0.0f)
        {
            nADamage += (0.75 * (bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN3P));
        }

        else
        {
            nADamage = bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN3P;
        }

        if (nHDamage > 0.0f)
        {
            nHDamage += (0.75 * (bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN3P));
        }

        else
        {
            nHDamage = bTarget.Ship->getSShield() * NAN3P;
        }

        if (sDNANTurns < NAN1T)
        {
            sDNANTurns = NAN3T;
        }
    }
}

float Damage::processSecDamage(bTarget& bTarget)
{
    if (getSDNTurns())
    {
        tSDamage += sDamage;
    }

    if (getSDNANTurns())
    {
        //Direct damage
        bTarget.Ship->setSShield(bTarget.Ship->getSShield()-nSDamage);
        bTarget.Ship->setSArmor(bTarget.Ship->getSArmor()-nADamage);
        bTarget.Ship->setSHull(bTarget.Ship->getSHull()-nHDamage);
    }

    return tSDamage;
}

bool Damage::getSDNTurns()
{
    return sDNTurns > 0;
}

bool Damage::getSDNANTurns()
{
    return sDNANTurns > 0;
}


void Damage::setupWQueue(bAttacker& bAttacker, string atype)
{
    cleanWQueue(); //Clear vector

    if (atype == "allout")
    {
        for (i = 0; i < bAttacker.Ship->getWVSize(); i++)
        {
            weaponQueue.push_back(bAttacker.Ship->getSHPoint(i));
        }
    }

    else if (atype == "spread")
    {
        for (i = 0; i < bAttacker.Ship->getSSize(); i++)
        {
            weaponQueue.push_back(bAttacker.Ship->getSHPoint(i));
        }
    }

    else if (atype == "wsystem")
    {
        for (i = 0; i < bAttacker.Ship->getWVSize(); i++)
        {
            weaponQueue.push_back(bAttacker.Ship->getSHPoint(i));
        }
    }

    else if (atype == "single")
    {
        weaponQueue.push_back(bAttacker.Ship->getWVHPoint(0));
    }
}


void Damage::cleanWQueue()
{
    weaponQueue.clear();
}


void Damage::setupBAT(Entity* entity1, Entity* entity2)
{
    bAttacker bAttacker;
    bTarget bTarget;

    bAttacker.getShip(entity1);
    bTarget.getShip(entity2);

    dmgProcessing(bAttacker, bTarget);
}



//bAttacker

void bAttacker::getShip(Entity* entity)
{
    Ship = entity->Ship.rShip(); //Create an easy to use interface to get the ship data
}


//bTarget

void bTarget::getShip(Entity* entity)
{
    Ship = entity->Ship.rShip();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally gave up and just moved and combined bAttacker and bTarget into a new class called bEntity (battle entity) and referenced it twice to create two instances of bEntity for both the Target and Attacker identifiers.

Works fine that way, I suppose the problem was in that you cannot define multiple non-related classes and access them normally (you can do that but the main class has to have a reference or pointer to the other classes in the header).

Another reason might be because I forgot the constructors in the cpp file for bAttacker and bTarget but I like my new set up better anyway, much more compact.